Getting ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 because the content of a POST contains the word "Filestore"
Web server is throwing an error ModSecurity; Access denied with code 403, [Rule:'ARGS' '@pmFromFile bl_db_domains'] [id '77316744"] [msg "IM360 WAF: Block by unknown DB injecion entry || Injection:filestore] ... [Severity "CRITICAL"]. I tracked the problem to the content of the POST, which has the word "Filestore" inside the text.
Why is this happening, and what can I do. It is on a hosted server, so I do not have access to the ModSecurity rules. I believe "Filestore" is being blocked by Google.
My Application gets freeform text input from a web application. On Submit, POST the input for server action.
If the text contains the word Filestore, it throws an error "Access to mywebsite.com was denied. You don't have authorizaation to view this page HTTP Error 403"

CRS dev-on-duty here. Even if this is obviously not a CRS rule, I'll try to help here.
If you don't have access to your ModSecurity configuration, you should ask your hosting provider to write a rule exclusion. Examples for rule exclusions are:
SecRuleUpdateTargetById 77316744 "!ARGS:<your_argument>" (I'm not sure, which argument triggered the rule) But with this command you remove the check of a specific argument for this rule.
SecRuleRemoveById 77316744 -> but this would remove the entire rule! This is a bigger hole in your WAF.
Ask your hosting provider, how they handle rule exclusions.

Thanks for the response. I did get the admins on my hosting service to add the term. For the record, it is a single Enlish word - "Filestore". I think that Google has somehow laid claim to that word and there's an automatic redirect to their service.
